# How to keep variable's value from the previous step?

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

I’m testing an app that sending/receiving alerts.

In my tests, I send an alert, waiting to receive it and then check its content.

So, the steps are (with my functions):

```
Then /I send an alert/ do    
  alertTime = Time.new    
  enterAlertHeader(“New alert - #{ alertTime.sec }”)    
  pressSendButton    
end


Then /I open the alert/ do
  pressOnText(“New alert - #{ alertTime.sec }”)
end
```

In the second step, the `alertTime` changed to 0

How can I keep the value?

Do I need to write to a file and then read it?

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cucumber World variable.  In the example below, the @shared_alert_time is a World variable.  I recommend not over using variables to save state.  However, sometimes it is necessary and/or convenient.

```
Then /I send an alert/ do    
  @shared_alert_time = Time.new    
  enterAlertHeader("New alert - #{ @shared_alert_time.sec }")    
  pressSendButton
end


Then /I open the alert/ do
  pressOnText("New alert - #{ @shared_alert_time.sec }")
end
```

Comment: Now it is brings me to the next issue.
the value been reset when the test move to the next scenario (reload the app). how do i keep these values for more than 1 scenario?

Comment: found it - use '$' instead '@'

Comment: $ is a global variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SharedPreferences and here is the Developer Guides: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)